# Round all columns in dataframe - two decimal place pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this command for all columns in my dataframe to round to 2 decimal places:

```
data = data.withColumn("columnName1", func.round(data["columnName1"], 2))
```

I have no idea how to round all Dataframe by the one command (not every column separate). Could somebody help me, please? I don't want to have the same command 50times with different column name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not a function or command for applying all functions to the columns but you can iterate.

```
+-----+-----+
| col1| col2|
+-----+-----+
|1.111|2.222|
+-----+-----+

df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test.csv")

for c in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(c, f.round(c, 2))
    
df.show()

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|1.11|2.22|
+----+----+
```

**Updated**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.select(*[f.round(c, 2).alias(c) for c in df.columns]) \
  .show()

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|1.11|2.22|
+----+----+
```

Comment: `df = df.withColumn(c, round(df.col(c), 2))`

Comment: If in my df there are two columns that can't round, because is date. How I to exclude the columns in transformation round?

Comment: TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method

Comment: worked fine for me !

Comment: It should be f.round in the 1st part of the answer instead of just round. By default it would pick python round function.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid converting non-FP columns:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
for c_name, c_type in df.dtypes:
    if c_type in ('double', 'float'):
        df = df.withColumn(c_name, F.round(c_name, 2))
```