# Round df.describe() results

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-colaboratory

Is there any way to set decimals in the `describe()` function? I want the result to only show 2 decimals.

[image]

Comment: As there is no dataframe.round() pandas like function in pyspark so you will have to manually round all columns in a loop like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723965/round-all-columns-in-dataframe-two-decimal-place-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any built in spark feature to do exactly that, but you can round all the columns yourself like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.describe()\
  .select('summary', *[f.round(c, 2).alias(c) for c in df.columns])\
  .show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The describe method returns a DataFrame so you can just use the DataFram round method:

df.describe().round(2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).